# setTimeout doesn't work with remove class on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

setTimeout doesn't work with remove class on hover. What can I do?

```
$( ".control-btn" ).hover(
    function() {
        $(this).find(".dropdown-content").addClass("dropdown-content-active");
    }, function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $(this).find(".dropdown-content").removeClass("dropdown-content-active");
      }, 200);
    }
  );
```

Comment: Please also add your HTML and CSS so we can replicate your issue.

Answer (score 3):

```
$( ".control-btn" ).hover(
    function() {
        $(this).find(".dropdown-content").addClass("dropdown-content-active");
    }, function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      setTimeout(function() {
        $this.find(".dropdown-content").removeClass("dropdown-content-active");
      }, 200);
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

When the `setTimeout()` executes, the `this` binding is altered and no longer points to your `.control-btn` element. In the timer's callback, you must specify which element you want to work with.

```js
$( ".control-btn" ).hover(
    function() {
        $(this).find(".dropdown-content").addClass("dropdown-content-active");
    }, function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $( ".control-btn" ).find(".dropdown-content").removeClass("dropdown-content-active");
      }, 200);
    }
);
```

```css
.dropdown-content-active { background-color:yellow; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>

  <div class="control-btn">Hello
  
    <div class="dropdown-content">TEST</div>
  </div>
</div>
```